# C# Separating An Array Into Multiple Smaller Arrays (Randomly)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, discord

I am making a DISCORD.NET BOT for my friends and I in c# and this is my first time using this language (I work with VB.NET but the syntax is entirely new to me here).

My "issue" is that one of my commands "!squads" takes in any number of usernames and will split the users into teams so that we don't have to do it ourselves and feel bad about who gets picked last. I won't explain my code it's included below and quite simple.

My question revolves around when 6 or 7 names are entered, 5 was simple to do. But with 6 I would like two teams of 4 and 2, and with 7 two teams of 4 and 3 **PICKED AT RANDOM.**

Here are my thoughts on how to do this but I think it will be messy, so I'd like some pointers please! For 6 names, create 2 arrays with max items of 2 and 4, fill the 2 randomly first, and push the rest to the 4. With 7 do the same, fill the team of 3 first and then push the rest to the 4. I believe this to be a more efficient way than going back and forth from array to array. But, I will need to probably remove the selected user from the main array, re-index the array every time so I don't pick the same person over again, and also change the number of the max in the random generator that selects the index. I can do all this but it would be so sloppy, is there a way to do this cleanly without 60-70 lines of for and if loops?

Here is my code, and thank you! :)

```
[Command("Squads")]
    public async Task CreateSquads(params string[] usersArray)
    {

        int totalUsers = usersArray.Length;
        Random squadSelector = new Random();
        string squadsMessage;

        if (totalUsers < 5)
        {
            squadsMessage = "I am sensing 4 or less names, just play squads, clowns.";
        }
        else if (totalUsers == 5)
        {
            string selectedUser = usersArray[squadSelector.Next(0, usersArray.Length)];
            squadsMessage = "Tough luck " + selectedUser + ", better luck next time!";
        }
        else if (totalUsers == 6)
        {
            // Split users into two teams of 2 and 4
            squadsMessage = "6 people."; // Placeholder
        }
        else if (totalUsers == 7)
        {
            // Split users into two teams of 3 and 4
            squadsMessage = "7 people."; // Placeholder
        }
        else
        {
            // More than 7 people. (not coding for this)
            squadsMessage = "We have this many friends? Wut.";
        }

        // Originally used this just to spit out the names for testing
        //for (int i = 0; i < totalUsers.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(totalUsers[i]);
        //}

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(squadsMessage);
```

UPDATED CODE, WORKS PERFECTLY! THANKS ALL! :)

```
[Command("Squads")]
    public async Task CreateSquads(params string[] usersArray)
    {

        string[] squadOne;
        string[] squadTwo;

        int totalUsers = usersArray.Length;
        Random squadSelector = new Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string squadsMessage;

        if (totalUsers < 5)
        {
            squadsMessage = "I am sensing 4 or less names, just play squads, morons.";
        }
        else if (totalUsers >= 5 && totalUsers <= 7)
        {
            // 5 users becomes 4 and 1; 6 users becomes 4 and 2; 7 users becomes 4 and 3
            usersArray = usersArray.OrderBy(i => squadSelector.Next()).ToArray();

            squadOne = usersArray.Take(4).ToArray();
            squadTwo = usersArray.Skip(4).Take(totalUsers - 4).ToArray();

            sb.Append("__**Squad One:**__");
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < squadOne.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(squadOne[i]);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            if (totalUsers == 5)
            {
                sb.Append("__**LOL, Loser:**__");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("__**Squad Two:**__");
            }

            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < squadTwo.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(squadTwo[i]);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            squadsMessage = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            // More than 7 people.
            squadsMessage = "We have this many friends? Wut.";
        }

        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(squadsMessage);

    }
```

Comment: Well, I'm not saying any of these are hard, but 5 was easy to do in 2 lines, I would like to keep 6 and 7 as compact as possible. I just don't see how I can do this efficiently and in as little lines as possible. Also, I may be over thinking this, I've never had to do this before I don't think.

Comment: @mjwills: By the looks of the code the difference is that 5 had a team of one and a team of "the rest" so it just needed to select one person at random and announce who that person was. This could be extended but as the OP correctly realises that wouldn't necessarily be the best way to do it.

Comment: @Chris Precisely, the accepted answer below was perfect for what I needed though. I will probably apply this to my case of 5 items in the array and include the one person into their own team, to further the laugh. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will do it like this:

```
var usersArray = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
var r = new Random();
usersArray = usersArray.OrderBy(i => r.Next()).ToArray();
var firstGroup = usersArray.Take(3).ToArray();
var secondGroup = usersArray.Skip(3).Take(4).ToArray();
```

The line with OrderBy(i => r.Next()) will order them randomly. Then you can easily split items in 2 groups.
You can also extract this code to the method :)

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you very much. I completely forgot about using LINQ. It spits out the first team very quick and then there is a short delay for the second, but I assume this may be due to my laptop capabilities.

Comment: @haag1: Those last two lines should both run virtually instantly. If the delay is just your bot outputting two lines of text then that may just be either throttling of the bot or network latency (as it waits for one line to be confirmed before sending the next). The actual run time for skipping and taking from an array of 7 items should be basically zero though.

Comment: @Chris I figured out my issue, it was the dispensing of the teams separately to the server, I decided to include a stringbuilder and append the entire two teams into one string and then send it. Problem solved (: